# Unable to download Drive files using googleapis in a Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I'm using googleapis library in my Node.js server to download media files from Google Drive. The code works perfectly fine on my local machine, but when I deploy the server, it's not able to download the files. "I'm using Render as my server. I attempted to use Railay, but I was unsuccessful.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
const express = require("express");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
require("dotenv").config();

const process = require("process");
const router = express.Router();

const SCOPES = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata",
];
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), "service.json");

//Download Files on server
let downloadFiles = async (driveFiles, drive) => {
  let dirname = __dirname.split("Routes").join("");

  // Create an array of Promises that will resolve when the file is downloaded and read
  const promises = driveFiles.map((item) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const url = item.fileLink;
      const fileId = url.split("d/")[1].split("/view")[0];

      //Get the file data using fileID to get file name
      drive.files.get({ fileId: fileId }, (er, re) => {
        // Added
        if (er) {
          console.log(er);
          reject(er);
          return;
        }
        const fileName = re.data.name;
        const filePath = `${dirname}public\\${fileName}`;
        const dest = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);

        //Get the file stream from drive and save to the desired path.
        drive.files.get(
          { fileId: fileId, alt: "media" },
          { responseType: "stream" },
          function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              reject(err);
            }
            res.data
              .on("end", () => {
                item.serverURL = `${process.env.SERVER_URL}/${fileName}`;
                resolve(item);
              })
              .on("error", (err) => {
                console.error("Error downloading file.");
                reject(err);
              })
              .pipe(dest);
          }
        );
      });
    });
  });

  // Wait for all the Promises to resolve before returning the results
  const results = await Promise.all(promises);
  return results;
};

router.post("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  let folderId = req.params.id;
  let fileURLs = req.body.fileURLs;

  //get auth
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
    scopes: SCOPES,
  });

  //get drive
  const drive = google.drive({
    version: "v3",
    auth,
  });

  let resultURLs = await downloadFiles(fileURLs, drive);
  console.log("result array Sent Successfully");
  return res.json(resultURLs);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I want to download these files on the server because I need to add them to Airtable. I have tried using the Drive files' download URL for attachments, but it doesn't work for some files.

I attempted to download the files from Google Drive onto the server using both the https module and axios, using the Drive file download URL.

Can anyone help me figure out why the files are not being downloaded on the server? Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!